# How to use laravel-websockets with nginx reverse proxy on google app engine?

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, nginx, websocket

I'm trying to deploy the [laravel-websockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) into a google app engine service and don't manage ssl certificates. App engine "google frontend" will only forward port 80 and 443 to the custom user nginx.conf file that listen in port 8080. So after deployed there is no erros and the google stackdriver logs show me that the websocket service is accepting connections, but the frontend service don't show me anything, no erros and no success. So what I'm missing?

Currently nginx.conf for this service is:

```
daemon off;

user  root;
worker_processes  auto;
error_log /dev/stderr info;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:6001;
            proxy_read_timeout     60;
            proxy_connect_timeout  60;
            proxy_redirect         off;

            # Allow the use of websockets
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
}
```

and my app.yaml file:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

service: websockets

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2
  disk_size_gb: 10

runtime_config:
  document_root: public
  enable_stackdriver_integration: true

readiness_check:
  app_start_timeout_sec: 1800

env_variables:
  // all basic laravel env here plus:

  BROADCAST_DRIVER: pusher

  PUSHER_APP_ID: testing
  PUSHER_APP_KEY: testing
  PUSHER_APP_SECRET: testing
```

My pusher config in broadcast.php file is

```php
'pusher' => [
    'driver'  => 'pusher',
    'key'     => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret'  => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id'  => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'host'      => 'my-websockets-service-generated-domain.appspot.com',
        'port'      => '443',
        'scheme'    => 'https',
        'encrypted' => true
    ],
],
```

And finally my settings on the client side:

```
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js')

const echo = new Echo({
  authEndpoint: 'my-backend-service-generated-domain.appspot.com/broadcasting/auth',
  broadcaster: 'pusher',
  key: 'testing',
  httpHost: 'my-websockets-service-generated-domain.appspot.com',
  httpsPort: 443,
  disableStats: true,
  encrypted: true
})
```

The google stackdriver logs:

[image: google stackdriver logs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it! On the client side in the Echo settings I need to use `wsHost` and update the `wsPort` and `wssPort` to use 80 and 443, the nginx reverse proxy will proxy it to the 6001

```
broadcaster: 'pusher',
key: 'testing',
wsHost: 'my-websockets-service-generated-domain.appspot.com',
wsPort: 80,
wssPort: 443,
disableStats: true,
encrypted: true
```

Comment: Did you keep your broadcast.php set to https and 443 or switch to http and 6001?

Comment: @Munsterlander Looked in the version control and it was 443, but this project isn't active anymore so I cannot help more than that.

Comment: No problem.  I am having a similar issue and trying to get this going.

Comment: @Munsterlander did you make it finally? :)